# How do i stop the countdown and reset the starting value, without exiting the mainloop?

Tags: python, tkinter

How do i stop the countdown and reset the starting value, without exiting the mainloop?

Code:

```py
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

i=100

def countdown():
    global l1, i, root
    l1.config(text=i)
    i -= 1
    root.after(1000, countdown)
    
    
l1=Label(root, text='' )
l1.pack()

countdown()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you want to stop the countdown when `i` reaches 0? if so the easiest way would be to place `after` under an if condition( `if i>0`)

Comment: You need to save the returned value of `root.after(...)` and use that value on `root.after_cancel()` to stop the countdown.

Comment: Hi JacksonPro, thanks. the condition (if i>0) works.

Comment: Hi acw1668, I am still not sure how to use the root.after_cancel here. Let me search thru the examples and the answers how to use this. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `after_cancel(id)` to stop the `after()` calls. So it goes something like:

```py
def countdown():
    global i
    l1.config(text=i)
    i -= 1
    rep = root.after(1000, countdown)
    if i < 0: # Use i <= 0 if you don't want to include 0
        root.after_cancel(rep)
```

You can further improve your code by removing the `global` and passing the current reduced time as parameter to the function, like:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

i = 100
def countdown(sec):
    l1.config(text=sec)
    sec -= 1
    rep = root.after(1000,countdown,sec) # Passes sec as argument to countdown
    if sec < 0:
        root.after_cancel(rep)
    
l1 = Label(root)
l1.pack()

countdown(i) # Pass initial time as sec parameter to the function

root.mainloop()
```

Also keep in mind, there is no guarantee `after(ms,func)` will call the function after exactly `ms` millisecond, it can get delayed further to maybe `ms+0.001` or `ms+0.5` or whatever milliseconds as well. The only guarantee is that, it will not call the function before the supplied `ms`.

Comment: `after_cancel()` is not necessary in your case, just call `root.after(...)` if `i > 0` in first case and if `sec > 0` in second case.  `.after_cancel()` is used in case you want to cancel the countdown before reaching 0.

Comment: @acw1668 I know, it was given so that the user can expand on it if needed. The other solution was given in the comments itself